# Searching files inside nested zip using C#

Tags: c#, linq, zip, file-search

I have folder that contains zip folders. Those zip files may have zip folders inside them. I need to search for a particular file using its pattern which may be inside any of the nested zips. What would be the best way to get them in c#

Answer (score 0):

Try using the ZipArchive Class

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2

It lets you read without extracting.